# Change website shown in webView after which tab you've selected

Tags: android

What I want to do is when you visit the tab "short" it will load "short.php", when you visit "images" it will load "images.php" etc. How do I get that to work?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.themeister.feed.it;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {


/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("http://feedit.themeister.se/test.php");
// Set up the action bar.
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
// primary sections of the app.
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
        getSupportFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

// When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
// tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
// a reference to the Tab.
mViewPager
        .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

// For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
    // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
    // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
    // this tab is selected.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
            .setTabListener(this));
}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
// When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
// the ViewPager.
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
    // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
    case 1:
        return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
    case 2:
        return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
    }
    return null;
}
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.
 */
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public DummySectionFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
            container, false);
    WebView wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.loadUrl("http://dns.themeister.se/test.php");
    return rootView
            ;
}
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:weightSum="1"
          android:orientation="vertical">       
<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.9"/>    
<ProgressBar 
 android:id="@+id/progressbar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.1"         
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can see that you have posted more questions on the subject where you have problems making the webview show. Is that the real issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show webview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968282/how-to-show-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something but is it not simply adding a static method to DummySectionFragment:

```
 public static DummySectionFragment newInstance(String loadurl) {
    DummySectionFragment frag = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("url", loadurl);

    frag.setArguments(bundle);

    return frag;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final String url=getArguments().getString("url");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,container, false);
    WebView wv = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.loadUrl("http://dns.themeister.se/"+url+".php");
    return rootView;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
    // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

    return DummySectionFragment.newInstance(getPageTitle(position).toString());
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this code? Should I use the code above instead of my current DummySectionFragment? Or put it under it? Maybe inside DummySectionFragment?

Comment: The getItem goes into MainActivity and the rest inside your DummySectionFragment as I wrote. Though, I see you got a working answer in one of the other questions you posted, so guess this is not a necessary change?

Comment: just pasting the code pretty much gives me 3 errors. 1. "Syntax error on token "url",, expected"
2. "The method loadUrl(String, Map<String,String>) in the type WebView is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"
3. "The method newInstance(String) in the type MainActivity.DummySectionFragment is not applicable for the arguments (CharSequence)"

Comment: Made minor edits. To be honest you should be able to correct them and report it instead of throwing the errors back. I mean, I do not have your codebase and hence have not run it. 1) ...+"url"+... changed to "+url+" 2) .toString()